# Issue with Custom TagHelper (Autocomplete) when used inside a List of Items (being displayed with EditorFor)

Tags: autocomplete, asp.net-core-mvc, tag-helpers

We have written a custom `TagHelper` to handle Autocomplete in a generic fashion. It has an asp-for attribute, which is defined as as ModelExpression variable.

The autocomplete `TagHelper` writes out a hidden field (the Id field), as well as an Input field for the autocomplete js code to work on. It ultimately saves the selected items Id value to the hidden field. This autocomplete works very well for multiple fields on a form.

But when the autocomplete `TagHelper` is incorporated in a list of items using an `EditorTemplate` to display all items the same (using `EditorFor` on a List in  the model), then we need to set the Z index based name on the hidden field so it comes back to the controller as a List of the items. e.g. `z0__*Field*`, `Z1__*Field*`, ...

- How do we get the Z index based name prefix that needs to be tacked on to the front of all the field names?
- Do we have to make it up ourselves?
- or do we extract from the `ModelExpression` somehow?
- The Standard Input `TagHelper` is getting handled correctly?
- Is the `EditorFor`/`EditorTemplate` the correct way to handle lists of editable objects in ASP.NET Core 1?

Autocomplete TagHelper

```
public class AutocompleteTagHelper : TagHelper
{
    public ModelExpression AspFor { get; set; }

    public ModelExpression AspValue { get; set; }

    //public string AspFor { get; set; }

    public string Route { get; set; }
    public string RouteParameters { get; set; }
    public string TargetWrapper { get; set; }
    public string DisplayFormat { get; set; }
    public string ValueFormat { get; set; }

    public string ManageListCallback { get; set; }
    public string ListWrapper { get; set; }

    public string Placeholder { get; set; }

    private SkillDbContext _context;
    private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;
    private IMemoryCache cache;
    public AutocompleteTagHelper(SkillDbContext Context, UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager, IMemoryCache cache)
    {
        _context = Context;
        _userManager = userManager;
        this.cache = cache;
    }

    public override void Process(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
    {
        var hiddenVal = "";
        var displayVal = "";
        //asp-for="LandingPointId" 
        //route="/Lookups/GetLandingPoint" 
        //route-parameter="SomeOtherId" 
        //target-wrapper="form" key="Id" 
        //label="{Name} ({Code})" 
        //output="{code}"
        //AspFor.

        //get parent model from AspFor

        object thisModel = null;

        //get value properties
        if (AspValue != null)
        {
            hiddenVal = ValueFormat;
            displayVal = DisplayFormat;

            thisModel = AspValue.Model;

        }
        else if (AspFor.Model != null && !AspFor.Model.Equals((object)0))
        {
            Object Id = AspFor.Model;
            string routeMethod = Route.Split('/').Last<string>();
        }

        if(thisModel != null)
        {
            PropertyInfo[] propertyInfo = thisModel.GetType().GetProperties();
            foreach (var info in propertyInfo)
            {
                var val = info.GetValue(thisModel);
                if (val != null)
                {
                    hiddenVal = hiddenVal.Replace(("{" + info.Name + "}"), val.ToString());
                    displayVal = displayVal.Replace(("{" + info.Name + "}"), val.ToString());
                }

            }
        }
        var isAcList = ManageListCallback != null && ListWrapper != null;

        string aspForName = AspFor.Name.Replace(".", "_");
        output.TagName = "input";    // replaces <email> with <a> tag
        inputId = inputName = aspForName;
        output.Attributes["id"] = aspForName;
        output.Attributes["name"] = aspForName;
        output.Attributes["type"] = "text";

        output.Attributes["route"] = Route;
        output.Attributes["route-parameters"] = RouteParameters;
        output.Attributes["target-wrapper"] = TargetWrapper;

        output.Attributes["placeholder"] = Placeholder;

        output.Attributes["value-format"] = ValueFormat;
        output.Attributes["display-format"] = DisplayFormat;
        output.Attributes["value"] = displayVal;

        output.Attributes["class"] = "autocomplete form-control" + (isAcList?" hasList":"");

        TagBuilder HiddenValue = new TagBuilder("input");
        HiddenValue.Attributes["name"] = inputName;
        HiddenValue.Attributes["id"] = inputId + "_hidden";
        HiddenValue.Attributes["type"] = "hidden";
        HiddenValue.Attributes["value"] = hiddenVal;

        output.PreElement.SetContent(HiddenValue);

        if (isAcList)
        {
            TagBuilder AddBtn = new TagBuilder("a");

            AddBtn.Attributes["id"] = AspFor.Name.Replace(".", "_") + "_submit";
            AddBtn.Attributes["class"] = "moana-autocomplete-list-manager disabled btn btn-primary";
            AddBtn.Attributes["listwrapper"] = ListWrapper;
            AddBtn.Attributes["href"] = ManageListCallback;

            AddBtn.InnerHtml.AppendHtml("Add");
            output.PostElement.SetContent(AddBtn);
        }

    }
```

This is the model

```
public class AddressEditorModel 
{

    public  int Id { get; set; }

    public string AddressLinkTo { get; set; }

    public int AddressLink { get; set; }

    public string AddressLine { get; set; }

    public int ContactTypeId { get; set; }

    public string Suburb { get; set; }

    public string City { get; set; }

    public string Postcode { get; set; }

    public int? CountryId { get; set; }

    public string ContactTypeName { get; set; }

    public string CountryCode { get; set; }
    public string CountryName { get; set; }
}
```

This is the cshtml

```
@model List<Skill.ViewModels.AddressEditorModel>

<div class="address-info-wrapper">
    @Html.EditorFor(m => m)
<div>
```

This is the controller method call

```
public async Task<IActionResult> UpdateAddressInfo(List<AddressEditorModel> addresses)
```

and finally this is the EditorTemplate

```
@model Skill.ViewModels.AddressEditorModel

<input type="hidden" asp-for="Id" />
<input type="hidden" asp-for="ContactTypeId" />
<input type="hidden" asp-for="AddressLink" />
<input type="hidden" asp-for="AddressLinkTo" />
<input type="hidden" asp-for="CountryId" />

<label class="col-md-12 control-label" style="padding-bottom:20px;">@Model.ContactTypeName</label>
<div class="form-group">
    <label asp-for="AddressLine" class="col-md-2 control-label">Address</label>
    <div class="col-md-10">
        <input asp-for="AddressLine" class="form-control" style="resize:both" />
        <span asp-validation-for="AddressLine" class="text-danger" />
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label asp-for="Suburb" class="col-md-2 control-label">Suburb</label>
    <div class="col-md-10">
        <input asp-for="Suburb" class="form-control" />
        <span asp-validation-for="Suburb" class="text-danger" />
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label asp-for="City" class="col-md-2 control-label">City</label>
    <div class="col-md-10">
        <input asp-for="City" class="form-control" />
        <span asp-validation-for="City" class="text-danger" />
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-md-2 control-label">Country</label>
    <div class="col-md-10">
        <autocomplete asp-for="CountryId" route="/Lookups/GetCountry" target-wrapper="form" display-format="{Name} ({Code})" value-format="{Id}"></autocomplete>
        <span asp-validation-for="CountryId" class="text-danger" />
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label asp-for="Postcode" class="col-md-2 control-label">Post Code</label>
    <div class="col-md-10">
        <input asp-for="Postcode" class="form-control" />
        <span asp-validation-for="Postcode" class="text-danger" />
    </div>
</div>
```

**Note that the autocomplete tag** above in the EditorTemplate generates its own internal tags (as part of the tag helper).

This is a portion of the page for the first Address Information (as shown in firefox)

```
<input id="z0__Id" type="hidden" value="5" name="[0].Id" data-val-required="The Id field is required." data-val="true">
<input id="z0__ContactTypeId" type="hidden" value="1" name="[0].ContactTypeId" data-val-required="The ContactTypeId field is required." data-val="true">
<input id="z0__AddressLink" type="hidden" value="1" name="[0].AddressLink" data-val-required="The AddressLink field is required." data-val="true">
<input id="z0__AddressLinkTo" type="hidden" value="F" name="[0].AddressLinkTo">
<label class="col-md-12 control-label" style="padding-bottom:20px;">Work</label>
<div class="form-group">
<label class="col-md-2 control-label" for="z0__AddressLine">Address</label>
<div class="col-md-10">
<input id="z0__AddressLine" class="form-control" type="text" value="4a Lansdowne Street" name="[0].AddressLine" style="resize:both">
<span class="text-danger field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-replace="true" data-valmsg-for="[0].AddressLine"> </span>
</div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<label class="col-md-2 control-label" for="z0__Suburb">Suburb</label>
<div class="col-md-10">
<input id="z0__Suburb" class="form-control" type="text" value="Bayswater" name="[0].Suburb">
<span class="text-danger field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-replace="true" data-valmsg-for="[0].Suburb"> </span>
</div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<label class="col-md-2 control-label" for="z0__City">City</label>
<div class="col-md-10">
<input id="z0__City" class="form-control" type="text" value="Auckland" name="[0].City">
<span class="text-danger field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-replace="true" data-valmsg-for="[0].City"> </span>
</div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<label class="col-md-2 control-label">Country</label>
<div class="col-md-10">
<input id="CountryId_hidden" type="hidden" value="1" name="CountryId">
<input id="CountryId" class="moana-autocomplete form-control ui-autocomplete-input" type="text" value="New Zealand (NZ)" display-format="{Name} ({Code})" value-format="{Id}" placeholder="" target-wrapper="form" route-parameters="" route="/Lookups/GetCountry" name="CountryId" autocomplete="off">
<span class="text-danger field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-replace="true" data-valmsg-for="[0].CountryId"> </span>
</div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<label class="col-md-2 control-label" for="z0__Postcode">Post Code</label>
<div class="col-md-10">
<input id="z0__Postcode" class="form-control" type="text" value="0604" name="[0].Postcode">
<span class="text-danger field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-replace="true" data-valmsg-for="[0].Postcode"> </span>
</div>
</div>
```

**Note that the Html.EditorFor generates the Z*n*__*fieldname* prefixes to the input name attribute as well as an [*n*].*fieldname* name for the input id attribute**

The issue is how to access the index value, or get this prefix to tack onto our generated inputs from inside the TagHelper i.e. the Z*n*__* or [*n*] value, which is essentially the indexor of the EditorFor as it generates the repeated fields

Thanks for any help

Comment: Would you provide a sample code for your Model, tag helper and editor template to get a better understanding?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok I have been working diligently on this. 
I eventually had to look at the TagHelpers from the Asp.Net core source project.

I found that we need to access the ViewContext.ViewData.TemplateInfo;
from inside the TagHelper.

Or alternately we could use the IHtmlGenerator object - calling a GenerateTextBox, GenerateHidden, etc to build the TageHelpers as required